# Add post variable to form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, local-storage

I have the below code which adds the value of the parameter to my form by default.  This works well but if you set the form to post then it no longer works.  What is the best approach to setting this value?

```
    var request = {};
    var pairs = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
            request[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

    var getfirstname = document.getElementById('firstname');

    var firstname = request['firstname'];

    getfirstname.setAttribute('value', firstname);


    <form method="get" action="search">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" />
        <input type="submit" alt="Go" value="Go" border="0" />
    </form>

        www.example.com?firstname=john

    <form method="get" action="search">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="John" />
        <input type="submit" alt="Go" value="Go" border="0" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers you've gotten so far probably don't address your issue correctly. If you are setting the value of an input from a form that is submitted with the method set to "GET" then the parameters are available in the querystring  and accessible by the browser - that's why this works:

```
var pairs = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
```

But when you change the method to "POST", the posted data is no longer available to the browser (client-side). You need to retrieve the posted data on the server-side. If you are using PHP you would do something like this (very very simplified version):

```
<?php 
   $firstname = (isset($_POST['firstname'])) ? $_POST['firstname']:'NA';
 ?>

  <form method="get" action="search">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" alt="Go" value="Go" border="0" />
 </form>
```

Hope that helps. If you can explain a little more about what you are trying to do I could add something to address an ajax via jQuery option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the value of a field set the value property not the value attribute

```
getfirstname.value = firstname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `value` attribute, set the actual *value*:

```
getfirstname.val(firstname);
```